# How to write over a column in pandas based on the value found in another corresponding column?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, data-analysis

I am looking to write over the value in the category column as a pre-specified value within a list.  The head of my DataFrame looks like this:

```
                       Product Category
0           Macbook Pro Laptop        -
1           LG Washing Machine        -
2         USB-C Charging Cable        -
3             27in FHD Monitor        -
4         USB-C Charging Cable        -
5        AA Batteries (4-pack)        -
6         USB-C Charging Cable        -
7         USB-C Charging Cable        -
8   Bose SoundSport Headphones        -
9       AAA Batteries (4-pack)        -
10        USB-C Charging Cable        -
11             ThinkPad Laptop        -
12       AA Batteries (4-pack)        -
13      AAA Batteries (4-pack)        -
14        USB-C Charging Cable        -
```

I want to replace the Category column with pre-specified values within lists that look like this:

```
con_elec = ['20in Monitor', 
         '27in 4K Gaming Monitor', 
         '27in FHD Monitor', 
         '34in Ultrawide Monitor', 
         'Flatscreen TV', 
         'Google Phone', 
         'Macbook Pro Laptop', 
         'ThinkPad Laptop', 
         'Vareebadd Phone', 
         'iPhone']
elec_acc = ['AA Batteries (4-pack)',
            'AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 
            'Apple Airpods Headphones',
            'Bose SoundSport Headphones',
            'Lightning Charging Cable',
            'USB-C Charging Cable',
            'Wired Headphones']
house_app = ['LG Dryer',
             'LG Washing Machine']
```

I want to test to see if the value within the Product column is in one of the following lists and then replace the '-' in the Category column with the corresponding category that the product will fall under.

I tried using the following if statement:

```
for product in df['Product']:
    if product in con_elec == True:
        df['Category'] = 'Consumer Electronics'
    elif product in elec_acc == True:
        df['Category'] = 'Electronic Accessories'
    elif product in house_app == True:
        df['Category'] = 'Household Appliances'
```

This code runs without error, but it doesn't change the value in the Category column of the DataFrame.  How do I go about actually getting the values in the category column to change to the desired category label?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {}
for v, lst in [('Consumer Electronics', con_elec), ('Electronic Accessories', elec_acc), ('Household Appliances', house_app)]:
    for vv in lst:
        d[vv] = v

df['Category'] = df['Product'].map(d)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       Product                Category
0           Macbook Pro Laptop    Consumer Electronics
1           LG Washing Machine    Household Appliances
2         USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
3             27in FHD Monitor    Consumer Electronics
4         USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
5        AA Batteries (4-pack)  Electronic Accessories
6         USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
7         USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
8   Bose SoundSport Headphones  Electronic Accessories
9       AAA Batteries (4-pack)  Electronic Accessories
10        USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
11             ThinkPad Laptop    Consumer Electronics
12       AA Batteries (4-pack)  Electronic Accessories
13      AAA Batteries (4-pack)  Electronic Accessories
14        USB-C Charging Cable  Electronic Accessories
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom function and use `map` with a `lambda` for it. Also keep in mind when you use `in` the `== True` is an overstatement and you could avoid using it:

```
def replacers(x):
    if x in con_elec:
        return 'Consumer Electronics'
    elif x in elec_acc:
        return 'Electronic Accessories'
    elif x in house_app:
        return 'Household Appliances'
```

And then:

```
df['Category'] = df['Category'].map(lambda x: replacers(x))
```